# Posting a comment to Fan Page Comment using XID

Tags: facebook, comments

I got Facebook permission for publish_stream for the user. Then I want to use the token key to post a message under a fan page's comment using XID.

I code my application according to [these](https://graph.facebook.com/374874179197702/feed?message=_MESSAGE_&access_token=_TOKEN_KEY_) instructions, but I have an error message:

> SETTINGS: Unrecognized pref_type 0 for NullProfileSettings pref name
>   default_non_connection_tab.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no `/feed` connection on a post; it should be `/comments`

Comment: Hi lgy! Thanks for your quick response I tried it but it is not working still... using https://graph.facebook.com/_XID_/comments?message=from%20web&access_token=_TOKENKEY_ doesn't help me post a message under the xid... it just displays the comments within the xid.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by 'xid' here - xid was a parameter on the old comments plugin - are you referring to a post on a page / in news feed / etc?

Comment: yup exactly, I got the xid from a post made within a fan page. I retrieved that by clicking on the root post's date. I would just like to post a comment reply on that post.

Comment: when you retrieve the post ID from the page's /feed connection it should be of the form nnnnnnnnnn_nnnnnnnnn, posting to /POST_ID/comments?message=comment should work

Comment: I gave that a try but then it doesn't work, have you tried it before?

Comment: Plenty of times, i was testing something with this yesterday :Are you sure you're making a POST request and not a GET request? if you can't figure out how to make a POST request, fake it by adding `&method=post` as a parameter on your GET request